# DAY_OF_WEEK return wrong value in Android Calendar

Tags: android

Calendar class returns wrong value while get the DAY_OF_WEEK from the below code snippet.

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
myCalendar.set(2015,05,14,13,0,0);
int dayOfTheWeek = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

It returns 1, instead of 4.

but while use the below code snippet it returns correct value. (i.e., 4)

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfTheWeek = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Am i miss something in it?

Comment: `Cursor` is part of the sdk, not of the ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Months are 0 based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH), it's better to use constants in `Calendar` class, like [Calendar.MAY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MAY).

Comment: So, cant we set the value  for calendar like this `myCalendar.set(2015,05,14,13,0,0);` ?

Comment: I didn't say you can't. But if you do, you have to use the right value, i.e for May it's "4" (or "04") not "05".